# how to return a newly created object when using sequelize transcation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a following function, which works, when passed a new user data . it saves the object and the child object into the mysql table successfully. but how do i return the object back , once saved to the database, given i'm using sequelize transaction.

```
static async add(user) {
    let transaction; 
      try {
          // get transaction
        transaction = await models.sequelize.transaction();

        //  *****how to return the newly created user *****************************************

        models.User.create(user).then(newUser => {
          const id = newUser.id;

           //save address 
          if(user.address){

              address.userId = id;
              models.Address.create(address); 

          }
        }).catch(error => {
          throw error;
        }); 

        await transaction.commit();

      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error); 
            // Rollback transaction 
          if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
          throw error;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You just mixed up two approaches: async/await and `then` chain. I recommend to use async/await and call `models.User.create(user)` as `const newUser = await models.User.create(user)`. Also don't forget to pass a transaction object to all sequelize queries inside it explicitly like this: `models.User.create(user, { transaction })`

Comment: @Anatoly - thanks. with this const newUser = await models.User.create(user, {transaction}); I don't have to await transaction. I need to create/save address object as well, once user is created. How do I do that with aysnc/await. would you mind give me sample code snippet?

Comment: `if(user.address){

              address.userId = id;
              await models.Address.create(address, { transaction }); 

          }`

Comment: @Anatoly - I know this is an old question but, I am still not sure if I'm doing this correctly. can you post complete code sample , on creating user , then address and returning the user object at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create an auto-transaction, use await and indicate `transaction` in models's `create` functions:

```
static async add(user) {
      try {
        const createdUser = await models.sequelize.transaction(transaction => {
          const newUser = await models.User.create(user, { transaction })
           //save address 
          if(user.address){
            address.userId = newUser.id;
            await models.Address.create(address, { transaction }); 
          }
          return newUser;
        });
        // if you are here it means transaction already commited
        return createdUser;
      } catch (error) {
          // if you are here it means transaction already rolled back
          console.log(error); 
          throw error;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I apologize in advance . one last request on this, I'm really stuck on this and have no idea on how to do this. if i have to update the address (user can have multiple address)  , when I am updating the user. how should i do this. I have created associations and now I can pull all the addresses for a user =>  const updateUser = await models.User.findOne({ where: { id: Number(id) },include: [ {model: models.Address, as: 'addresses'}] }); But when it comes to update, do i update everything at once?

Comment: You can update user and addresses at once using `set`+`save` or `update` method. See https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-set